# Strange behaviour in Python SocketServer

Tags: python, sockets

I have created a python socket server, using a class inherited from `SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler`, overriding `setup` and `handle` methods. Of cource, `SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.setup` is called at the end of my own `setup`.

This is my server class

```
class MyServer(SocketServer.ForkingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    timeout = 30
```

A typical forking socket server.

Here is how I run my server

```
while True:
        try:
            server = MyServer((host, port), MyRequestHandler)
            print('Server listening on', (host, port))
            server.timeout = 300  # seconds
            server.serve_forever()
        except:
            print('Error with server, retrying in 5 seconds...')
            print(sys.exc_info())
            sleep(5)
```

`host` and `port` are predefined, no problem with them.

Server works fine, except when clients count reaches 40. After this number, no new connections will be accepted, all will be refused. I checked this with a client test python script from my own system. Only 40!

Why **40**? I have checked source code for SocketServer and found nothing related to this. I currently have no clue regarding this issue. Any, and I really mean it, any help is appreciated :))

Thanks in advance

OS: CentOS 6.5

Comment: `CentOS 6.5 x86_64`, and `uname -a` output : `Linux CDSX001 2.6.32-220.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 14 04:00:16 GMT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Do you mean when the number of simultaneously connected clients reaches 40? Or when 40 connections have been made in total (not all at the same time)? What is the output of "ulimit -Hn" and "ulimit -Sn"?

Comment: I mean 40 simultaneous connections. After that, any request is refused. Both hard and soft limit are 1024, way more than the limit I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really have now idea how I missed this in source!

```
class ForkingMixIn:

    """Mix-in class to handle each request in a new process."""

    timeout = 300
    active_children = None
    max_children = 40
```

Yeah, now I see the `max_children` property.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

This is probably unrelated to Python. Tune your Linux kernel, in **testing** phase do stuff like:

- turn syncookies off
- increase file handles available for the user (every socket opened is also a file handle used - maybe you're running out of them?)
- look at stuff like this: http://people.redhat.com/alikins/system_tuning.html#tcp
- and: http://people.redhat.com/alikins/system_tuning.html#fds
- check if stuff like fail2ban is installed (http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)
- check if rate limits are applied by `iptables` (in **testing** phase you could do `iptables -F` after making sure that default chain policy is `ACCEPT`)
- and last but not in the very least, check `dmesg`, `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog`, etc

One thing that theoretically **might** be related to Python is `SO_REUSEADDR`:

http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml

Check if you have it set for your socket.

**UPDATE:**

I just realized that since the 40 connections that your socket server maxes out at is actually pretty low, the simplest option could be running your socket server through `systrace`, just use `-f` flag to track forked processes as well. You could e.g. start socket server, open 35 simultaneous connections, and then connect `systrace` to a running process and set up 5 more connections and see what `systrace` reports. Very often in such situations syscalls fail with errors that are visible in systrace and allow pinpointing root cause relatively easily.

Comment: AFAIK, file descriptors limit is 1024 per process, so this should not be my issue. In each fork, I connect to a MongoDB server, and also a log file, so roughly 3 fds are used for each fork. Another thing is I have tested a same socket server using raw sockets and multiprocessing module, and that one could accept about 500 clients simultaneously. Pretty different. But anyway, thank you and I will look into each of your suggestions.

Comment: I see lots of `possible SYN flooding on port xxxx. Sending cookies.` in `dmesg` and also `/var/log/messages`. Seems like a problem. How can I dig this more? I read this `http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enable-tcp-syn-cookie-protection/` and disabled (0-ed) syncookies, but it seems like it is a security issue. A little guide is very appreciated at this :-)

Comment: OK, see my own answer.

Comment: BTW, what should I do about SYN flooding warnings? I just ignore them for the time being, and enable protection again.